# Pagination API good practice

Tags: python, flask

My main function :

```
def get_data():
    try:
        response = send_request_to_get_data()

        // will get one dict output looks like :
        {
          "data": ['some datas.....'],
          "next": "api/data?top=100&skip=200",
        }

        if response.status_code == 200:
            if response.json().get("next"):
                first_paginated_response = get_paginated_data(response.json().get("next"))

                if response.status_code == 200:
                    if first_paginated_response.json().get("next"):
                        second_paginated_response = get_paginated_data(response.json().get("next"))

                        if response.status_code == 200:
                           if second_paginated_response.json().get("next"):
                               print('again...again....again....again...again)


def send_request_to_get_data():
    return rq.get('https://example.com')


def get_paginated_data(paginated):
    url = "https://example.com/{next}".format(next=paginated)
    return rq.get(url)
```

If "next" key is in response, i need to send another request for pagination api, but my if statement looks weird.

What is the good approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `while` loop and save the data like this:

```
response = send_request_to_get_data()
data = response['data']
while response.status_code == 200 and response.json().get("next"):
    response = get_paginated_data(response.json().get("next"))
    data.extend(response['data'])
```

Comment: How to append response and paginated_response output in same list?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the data (`response['data']`).  You could set `data = []` in the beginning and then use `data.extend(response['data'])`

Comment: response.json().get("next") always available in my first response, so while loop execute same thing, i need to get next from second paginated_response?

Comment: @MohamedSameer Edited the response to answer your questions.

Comment: after while, next line is response or paginated_response?

Comment: @MohamedSameer It must be `response`, so the next iteration will check `response.status_code` and the `next` key.

Comment: Yeah you right, then data.extend(paginated_response['data']), here paginated_response is a typo?

Comment: Edited to fix typo